# Data inside request.data not visible in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for CRUD operations. In my Project, I have function-based view taking `request` as parameter. I am aware of the fact that `request.data` is only applicable for DRF-Specific `requests`. I am also aware of the fact that it is a `QueryDict`.
I am taking input from HTML form as name, roll and city of a Student. But when I print the request.data (aka QueryDict), I only get `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and its value and found that other key-value pairs are missing. Where is my other data (i.e roll, name and city)

e.g `{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "JSACyyvAPqNcCPXNZQsNzPcca7ah3N7arkhFM9CuqpNammk6f43wQ4GyGg5QwU6w"}`

***forms.html (Template):***

```
<form class="form" action="/save-data/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="roll">Roll:</label>
    <input type="number" id="roll" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Roll Number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your City">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

***Views.py***

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def save_data(request):
    requested_data = request.data
    print(requested_data)
    return HttpResponse("Success", content_type='application/json')
```

It was supposed to contain other data fields as well!

Comment: Add your view and template (HTML form) to your question

Comment: Your input tags need to have a name attribute to submit data from the input with the name as the key  - `<input id="name" name="name" ... />`